# Orbeon 4.1 custom REST persistence

Tags: rest, orbeon

I have been struggling for over a week with trying to setup a custom ORBEON REST persistence.

I am using the Struts 2 MVC framework with the following configuration:

```
<action name="/crud/{appName}/{formName}/form/form.xhtml" class="com.example.CrudController" method="executeForm" />

<action name="/crud/{appName}/{formName}/data/{uuid}/data.xml" class="com.example.CrudController" method="executeData" />

<action name="/search/{appName}/{formName}" class="com.example.SearchController" />
```

The problem is that only the first action is being called.

From the Form Builder, when I click on a form record (say "foo"), this is called:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/mycontext/app/crud/myapp/library/form/form.xhtml
```

Notice that, myapp is the correct application name but library is not the correct form name (which should be "foo").

From Form Runner, when I try the "foo" summary or new pages, this is called:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/mycontext/app/crud/myapp/foo/form/form.xhtml
```

This time the form name is correct, however I expected a /search/... call instead. Nevertheless I tried responding with either the xform xml or a query result with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `/crud/myapp/library/form/form.xhtml` is normal: it isn't done by Form Runner to load your form, but to load your app-specific [section templates](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide/section-templates) library, which is stored in the reserved `library` form name. So most likely your implementation of the persistence API should return a 404, since it doesn't have a form `myapp/library`.

As to the query to `/crud/myapp/foo/form/form.xhtml` when you access the new page for a `myapp/foo`, this is just Form Runner loading the form definition for `myapp/foo`. The query to the search API is only done by the summary page, to list data  for a specific form.

Comment: Returning 404, on GET myapp/library, results Form Builder always opening an empty form. I returned a dummy xml element and it finally worked! Thank you.